# "Зал" или "зала"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Какая из форм более правильная? В литературе встречаются оба варианта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно "зал". "Зала" - это устаревшая форма.

Answer (score 3):

Kagami прав, но считаю важным внести уточнение. *Зала* является архаичной формой существительного *зал* лишь во втором значении (количественно менее употребительном), а именно 'просторная парадная комната в частном доме для торжественных случаев, для танцев и т.п.'. В первом значении 'большое помещение для многолюдных собраний, для занятий чем-л. и др. целей' употребляется лишь слово *зал*. Соответственно, только оно употребляется и в переносном значении (образованном при метонимическом переносе) 'совокупность людей, находящихся в таком помещении' *(зал рукоплескал)*. Таким образом, если мы хотим украсить свою речь архаичной формой, нужно помнить, что она не всегда тождественна современной. :)